# Configuration with name 'default' not found when Importing from Git

Tags: android, eclipse, git, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm Working in a project that first began in Eclipse. Then I migrated in Android Studio.

I work in a Mac, and everything is OK.
But then, when I try to download my Git Rep in my PC, I get this message:

```
Configuration with name 'default' not found
```

Here is my Project Organization:

```
SP-Mobile
  progressWheel ( Lib as a project )
  sPMobile ( Main Project )
    build.gradle (1) 
  build.gradle (top)
  settings.gradle (top)
```

build.gradle (1)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21'
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.spmkt.mobile"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
}

dependencies {
compile project(':progressWheel')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile files('libs/crashlytics.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.3.jar')
```

}

build.gradle (top)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

And finally settings.gradle

```
include ':progressWheel'
include ':sPMobile'
```

I have made some test, and when I remove dependencies to progressWheel, I have no more problem ( Code doesn't compile anymore, but sync succeed )

I guess my problem comes from this line :

```
compile project(':progressWheel')
```

But I can't figure out why on 1 computer everything is OK. and in another one it fails!

EDIT:
It seems that progressWheel is added like a module, but sPMobile no.

progressWheel has an .iml inside, but sPMobile doesn't.

EDIT 2:

It seems I have my SP-Mobile.iml in red, I don't know what it means, but my iml's lib is not red, so I could understand diference between .iml mac and pc...

Here is my .iml project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module external.linked.project.id="SP-Mobile" 
external.linked.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" 
external.root.project.path="$MODULE_DIR$" external.system.id="GRADLE" 
external.system.module.group="" external.system.module.version="unspecified" 
type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I also see this situation but I ignored this message. 
I waited to finish all initialization (sync + build) before I use Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that one or more of your library paths are incorrect so make sure your libraries are exist in the default path or you can remove them and reinsert from the GUI option Right click on project : `Open Module settings >> select app module >> dependencies >> Add from "+" icon and select module dependency` ...